# My notebook doesn't boot up

Tags: freeze

I have 19.04 Ubuntu on my notebook. I was installing amd drivers than a just normally restarted my notebook. And than this happens.
https://youtu.be/kc0BfPmf9MU

Comment: Check for any BIOS/firmware updates from the notebook vendor. the Ryzen's usually need the latest.

Answer (score 1):

The AMD Ryzen CPUs typically need the latest BIOS/firmware updates from the notebook/motherboard vendor.  The 2xxx series (like your picture shows) as well as the 3xxx series may possibly boot Ubuntu 18.04 or later with various kernel switches like acpi=0, which may reduce functionality (like seeing only one of 8 cores), but after applying firmware updates, the need for additional kernel switch is (hopefully) eliminated completely.  The Ubuntu 19.10 release with the 5.x kernel would be a better choice than 18.04 for a Ryzen 3xxx CPU.

Go to the vendor's web site, and under support, find  the latest download for your hardware.  Even a newly bought computer typically needs these updates.  Fortunately, many new computers have built-in flash capability, so you put the downloaded firmware onto a FAT USB stick, hit some function key at power-up (varies by machine, but there is usually a note on the post screen at power-up saying which key for flashing). Older machines require running a DOS executable, or even worse, a Windows executable.

Answer (score 0):

Which drivers did you use?

If the laptop is not even showing the BIOS/UEFI boot screen then it's not related to the OS, the fault is at a hardware level.. Try popping the battery out for 10 seconds then in again to do a hard reset